# Peak finding algorithm - Why global maximum, what are the applications?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, array-algorithms

I came across the Peak Finding Algorithm from the MIT Intro to Algorithms class. I was wondering what are some of the practical applications of the algorithm, for both the 1D and 2D cases? Also, why do we find the global maximum of a column in the 2D case, and not just a peak in the column?

Comment: This is a question probably better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's just following terminology, global max is the "peak" in that span, although, not necessarily the highest peak we can find. So any 'column peak' can be a start point to find a 2D peak(while in the algorithm, it's the global max)